# Python lxml webscraping Google only printing empty lists

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, python-requests

I've looked around for a solution to this problem but for the life of me I cannot figure it out!

This is my first attempt at writing anything in python, and what I want my script to do is load a list of subjects from a text file, generate a Google search URL, and scrape these URLs one by one to output the amount of 'results found:' according to Google, in addition to the links of the top 15 results.

My problem is that when I run my code, all that is printed are empty lists:

```
[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


[]


**END_OBJECT** 

..etc.
```

Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests



def iterate():
    with open("list.txt", "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if not line.strip():
                break
            yield line

output = open ("statistic_out.txt", "w")

for line in iterate():
    raw = line
    output.write(raw + " services")
    request = raw.replace(" ", "%20")
    page = requests.get('https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&tbs=ctr:countryAU&cr=countryAU&q=' + request + 'services%20-yellowpages%20-abs', verify=False)
    path = html.fromstring(page.text)
    #This will create a list of buyers:
    resultCount = path.xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]/text()')
    #This will create a list of prices
    print(resultCount)
    print('\n')
    resultUrlList1 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[1]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList2 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[2]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList3 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[3]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList4 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[4]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList5 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[5]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList6 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[6]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList7 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[7]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList8 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[8]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList9 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[9]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList10 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[10]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList11 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[11]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList12 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[12]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList13 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[13]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList14 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[14]/div/h3/a/text()')
    resultUrlList15 = path.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/li[15]/div/h3/a/text()')
    print(resultUrlList1)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList2)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList3)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList4)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList5)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList6)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList7)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList8)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList9)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList10)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList11)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList12)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList13)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList14)
    print('\n')
    print(resultUrlList15)
    print('\n')
    print("**END_OBJECT** \n")
```

The actual HTML structure is that of any Google search:
[image: Html structure]

Any help would be greatly appreciated - as I am completely lost as to why this is occurring.

EDIT:

It appears that my script is hitting Google's anti-bot protections and path.content shows messages along the lines of "This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot."

I'm unsure if there are easy ways to bypass this though will update if I find any.

Comment: If this is your **FIRST** attempt to write anything in Python, I'd strongly advise you write from something smaller... even like **HelloWorld** before you attempt to achieve this.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with RoR and have been coding in various similar languages for a long long while, Python seems simple enough - for me this is what I chose for my 'hello world!' equivalent exercise :)

Thanks though - I do appreciate the advice! I may take a step back, though have a feeling I'm just missing something syntactically or am trying to print something without converting to the correct format.

Comment: Not being rude, it's only because I smell repetitiveness from your code... anyway, you should try breaking down your code into smaller chunks and see **WHICH** part does not return expected result. Also check your **Xpath** and see if they are REALLY working.

Comment: No no that's completely fine and I definitely appreciate your advice! You're correct in that I need to sort out the efficiency of my code and implement some smarter loops for the printing, though I was planning on doing this after I know my outputs are working correctly. 

I've taken a look at printing the path variable, to recieve "<Element html at 0x2feca98>" (I'm not sure if this is desirable however). 

Also taken a look through firebug and verified that my Xpaths are correct, though all indications show they are. 

Still unsure but will keep taking it apart :)

Comment: "<Element html at 0x2feca98>" only means you've successfully parsed the html from string, it doesn't mean the page return is with correct content, for example. And does your for/loop file actually returning desire string? Using firebug only gives you a hint of xpath starting from **root** element (like absolute path) which in my experience usually fails in real practice, try using "class" or something like `.//h3/a//text()`...

Comment: Also, another strong advice, try doing it from python console -- started from loading the file => successful => iterate the lines and check the content => then use **requests** to get result from google => check page.content/text => do xpath etc.

Comment: Oh I think I may have figured out my problem. I checked page.content and  noticed that what was being loaded is Google's anti-spam page with "This page checks to see if it&#39;s really you sending the requests, and not a robot."

I didn't even think of this as a possibility!

Comment: This happens a lot in web scraping, perhaps look at [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) which simulate human interaction with an actual browser action.

Comment: Thanks again, will take a look now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't specify the `user-agent`. You need to send `user-agent` which will act as a "real" user visit. When a bot or browser sends a fake user-agent string to announce itself as a different client. Because [default `requests` `user-agent` is python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands it, blocks a requests and you receive a different HTML with an error that contains different elements which your code can't recognize and find.

You can read more about it in the blog post I wrote about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping.](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46)

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

Also, instead of creating 15 `resultUrlList`, you can iterate over all of them in a `for` loop:

```py
# .tF2Cxc CSS selector is a container with title, link and other data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

params = {
  'q': 'how to create minecraft server',
  'gl': 'us',
  'hl': 'en',
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(title, link, sep='\n')


----------
'''
How to Setup a Minecraft: Java Edition Server – Home
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
Minecraft Server Download
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
Setting Up Your Own Minecraft Server - iD Tech
https://www.idtech.com/blog/creating-minecraft-server
# other results
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't need to figure how to to make things work: how to bypass blocks, how to extract data, how to maintain script over time if something in HTML will be changed, etc. Instead you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "how to create minecraft server",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])

----------
'''
How to Setup a Minecraft: Java Edition Server – Home
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
Minecraft Server Download
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
Setting Up Your Own Minecraft Server - iD Tech
https://www.idtech.com/blog/creating-minecraft-server
# other results
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.